# The chess.com vs computer games celebrity category

Tags: engines, online-chess

I came upon chess.com playing against computer mode. I found a resemblance of two professional chess players over there. Do they really resemble their gameplay, though? Does the AI mimic their past plays?

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Comment: Nakamura played his bot a couple months ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ5yqDtkQXI I'd say from his comment "And it's playing my friggin' opening!" on game 2 that the bot probably indeed has a bit of his "personality" but I can't say for sure to which extent it goes. The bot also tried to flag him in the endgame, which Nakamura does a lot. Not sure if they kept it as-is when chess.com moved to their new bots UI though.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent some time playing the lower-rated bots, and can confirm they tend to have different "personalities". I'm not a strong enough player to explain exactly how they are different. However I have observed that some are more aggressive, and tend to gravitate towards particular openings depending on the color.

I know that Hikaru recently did a series of videos on youtube where he played against bots. When I saw the new bots, I had a feeling that it was for the purpose you describe.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know for sure. Chess.com is closed source so we will never know for sure. One thing I can tell you for sure, you're **NOT** playing the real Nakamura. It's nothing more than a tuned chess engine wrapped by smart marketing.

Why don't we take a look of PlayMagnus https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/a5ws9t/question_about_playmagnus/?

> The higher levels of the app actually makes some attempts to play like
> Magnus did at the various ages. It isn't nearly as good as I would
> like it to be (I was handicapped by an extreme shortage of development
> time and not having anything better than my MacBook available for
> tuning and testing), and I hope to find the time to do a better job
> some day, but at least it is true that analysis of Magnus' style,
> strength and opening choices through the years played some role in the
> development of these levels.
>
> The lower levels, however, are pure fiction. We didn't even have any
> games played by Magnus at these ages. We made these levels with the
> aim that every chess player - even someone who has just learned the
> rules - should be able to find some beatable level. Magnus 5, the
> lowest level of all, plays completely random legal moves. It has
> nothing to do with any research of how Magnus or any other 5 year old
> plays chess.

So think of like paying chess.com for a new careful strong tuned chess AI. Sorry, no Nakamura here.

I don't know what exactly was tuned. My guess:

- Playing strength
- Thinking time
- Static evaluation
- Search algorithms
- Piece square tables
- Search depth etc

Answer (score 1):

They said about individual bot (strengths and weaknesses) but haven't disclosed about the bots, representing professional players.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

no, i think its just the strength of the computer is matched with the computers image like the hikaru nakamura computer. It will play at his strength level.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder whether chess.com team fed the AI and train the agent with Hikaru Nakamura's already played game. It would be awesome if they do something like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's more than engine strength involved, as there are multiple personalities with the *same* listed strength. In order to believe this answer I'd need something better sourced than "I think".